# Load single-column CSV as value in R

Tags: r, csv, dataframe, chr

I would like to know how can I convert a single column CSV file (with header) in to a character list in R. I've tried loading it as a data.frame in RStudio and then using as.character but the software gives me a string with random comma separated numbers.

My file has almost 1000 rows and I cannot enter them manually by using

```
sample = c("97_278", "BR5-045", "10-409", ...)
```

My file looks like this (first 5 rows)

```
Samples
97_278
BR5-045
10-409
BR8-316
97_420
```

This is what I get by using as.character under the Values table

```
sample_char     "c(235, 310, 103, ..."
```

This is what I'm looking for

```
sample_char     chr [1:1000] "97_278" "BR5-045" "10-409"
```

with sample_char being the new variable.

Comment: Can you provide some sample data and code? Otherwise, we cannot reproduce your problem nor help you correct your code.

Comment: I will edit my original post accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've ended up doing it by using as.matrix and the basic character list function (c) afterwards. So it goes like this

```
 sample2 =as.matrix(sample)
 sample3 = c(sample2)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the question is still not clear , the expected thing you said can be achieved by this basic function . Correct me if i get this wrong .

```
> a <- read.csv("cor.csv",header = T,sep = ",",stringsAsFactors = F)
> a$Samples
[1] "97_278"  "BR5-045" "10-409"  "BR8-316" "97_420" 
> class(a$Samples)
[1] "character"
```

Comment: Thanks for your input! I've edited my post in order to explain better what I'm basically looking for.

Answer (score 0):

If it is a single column, `scan` would be better to read it as a `vector`

```
res <- scan("cor.csv", sep="", what = "", quiet=TRUE)
str(res)
#chr [1:6] "Samples" "97_278" "BR5-045" "10-409" "BR8-316" ...
```

If we need a `list` of values, `as.list(res)` can be used.

Comment: Thanks for your input! I've edited my post in order to explain better what I'm basically looking for.

Comment: @IoannisTikas  I think the example should work with the code I posted